# Помогите сделать синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

> Природой ей отведён лишь сентябрь, пока не ударят первые заморозки.

Затрудняюсь с подчёркиванием всех членов предложения и с тем, какой частью речи они выражены. Сказуемое "отведён" и подлежащее "природой"?

Comment: Школьный синтаксический разбор предложения  (в том числе СЛОЖНОГО) делается по учебнику Литневской, там есть вся информация https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p97   Дополнительно о графическом оформлении  https://itlang.ru/kak-sostavit-shemu-predlozheniya-osnovnye-vidy-s-primerami/    Также: https://geekhow.ru/raznoe/pravila-sozdaniya-shemy-predlozheniya/

Comment: Страница 96 у Литневской:   https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p96 В частности указывается вид сложноподчиненного предложения, средство связи (союз). Далее разбирается каждое предложение в составе сложного, причем сначала указывается основа (подл. и сказуемое).  Разбор может зависеть от учебного комплекса: есть упрощенный разбор (комплекс 2) и обычный разбор (комплексы 1 и 3).

Comment: Подлежащее не может быть выражено формой сущ. в Т.п.,  это только сущ. в И.п.   Это ГЛАВНОЕ, что нужно запомнить. Природой (Т.п.) – это реальный субъект действия в данном предложении. Сравнить: Природа (И.п.) отвела ей лишь сентябрь.

Comment: Вообще говоря, такие вопросы лучше задавать, например, на ресурсе https://otvet.mail.ru/russian/  Это специальный сайт для выполнения ДОМАШНИХ заданий. Там участники быстро решают такие задачи, дается несколько ответов. На этом форуме лучше задавать ПРОБЛЕМНЫЕ вопросы: что именно не получилось. К примеру, такой вопрос:  Как определить подлежащее и сказуемое в этом предложении? Мой вариант: Сказуемое "отведён" и подлежащее "природой"?  А здесь будет проверено ваше решение.

Comment: Спасибо большое за книгу Литневской! Запомню, подлежащее только в И.п.

Comment: Удачи вам! И приходите к нам с проблемными вопросами)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен обычный школьный синтаксический разбор?

***Природой ей отведён лишь сентябрь, пока не ударят первые заморозки.***

*Главное предложение*:

***cентябрь*** — подлежащее,

***отведён*** — именная часть сказуемого,

***ей*** — косвенное дополнение (дательный адресата),

**природой** — косвенное дополнение (творительный субъектный),

**лишь** — служебное слово.

Придаточное предложение:

**первые** — согласованное определениее,

**заморозки** — подлежащее,

**ударят** — глагольное сказуемое,

***пока не*** — служебное слово.

Части речи: *сентябрь* - существительное, *отведён* - краткое страдательное причастие, *ей* - личное местоимение 3 лица, *природой* - существительное, *лишь* - ограничительная частица; *пока не* - временной подчинительный союз, *заморозки* - существительное, *ударят* - глагол, *первые* - порядковое числительное (по некоторым концепциям - прилагательное).